# Docusign API integration issue

Tags: java, jersey, glassfish, docusignapi

I am trying to integrate Docusign in our Java (Java-11) application.

I am trying to use the JWT flow for the same. After having authorized the app, I could get to the point of creating getting the access token, however when trying to create an envelope and create an embededded request I am seeing the following error :

```
[2021-07-21 15:00:32.954] [EC2AMAZ-5EFUJD8] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] ERROR c.p.e.h.GovCloudBaseExceptionHandler@handleException:237 - -- handleException() - {}
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=text/html;charset=utf-8, type=class com.docusign.esign.model.EnvelopeSummary, genericType=class com.docusign.esign.model.EnvelopeSummary.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:232)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1091)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:874)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:834)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientResponse.readEntity(ClientResponse.java:363)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.InboundJaxrsResponse$2.call(InboundJaxrsResponse.java:126)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:229)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestSco
```

The createEnvelope Method in the following code is throwing the error

```
void CreateEnvelope()
        {
            // Create the envelope definition
            EnvelopeDefinition envelope = null;
            try {
                envelope = makeEnvelope("anur.puniyani@teliolabs.com", "Anur");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Call DocuSign to create the envelope
            //ApiClient apiClient = createApiClient("", bearerToken);
            
              
            
            
            EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient);
            EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = null  ;
            try {
                envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.createEnvelope("1a9c289e-f63d-4f63-b6cd-5c43af184603", envelope);
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            

             envelopeId = envelopeSummary.getEnvelopeId();
             System.out.println("Envelope ID (&(*&(&( !!!!= "+envelopeId);
        }
```

I used the following base url for the ApiClient constructor : https://account-d.docusign.com
As the one in my App dashboard (demo.docusign.com) did not seem to work for giving permissions and was throwing a page not found error.

Please help me and my colleague are stuck with this since the entire day. We tried contacting support but they don't give API support unless you have the license.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  I figured out that the basepath you're using is missing `/restapi` it should be `https://demo.docusign.com/restapi`. Also I incorrectly said docusign.net when it should be docusign.com

As far as I am aware, there is no class method to create the envelope directly within the EnvelopeDefinition. You will need to specify the various associated portions necessary for the API call to succeed.  This portion of code comes from eSignature example 002 in our Launcher.  I've made a few small changes to make it work with a single document. You'll need to send this envelope definition to the host "demo.docusign.net" :

```
package com.docusign.controller.eSignature.examples;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;
import com.docusign.esign.api.EnvelopesApi;
import com.docusign.esign.client.ApiClient;
import com.docusign.esign.client.ApiException;
import com.docusign.esign.model.Document;
import com.docusign.esign.model.EnvelopeDefinition;
import com.docusign.esign.model.EnvelopeSummary;
import com.docusign.esign.model.Recipients;
import com.docusign.esign.model.SignHere;
import com.docusign.esign.model.Signer;
import com.docusign.esign.model.Tabs;

class CreateEnvelope
        {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create the envelope definition
        String accessToken = "eyJ0eXAi......JgAkJuZ8A";
        String accountId = "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx";
        

        // Call DocuSign to create the envelope
        ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi");
        apiClient.addDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

        EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient);
        EnvelopeDefinition envelope = makeEnvelope("anur.puniyani@teliolabs.com", "Anur");
        try {
            EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.createEnvelope(accountId, envelope);

            String envelopeId = envelopeSummary.getEnvelopeId();
            System.out.println("Envelope ID = "+envelopeId);
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
              

     

        }

        private static EnvelopeDefinition makeEnvelope(String signerEmail, String signerName) {
            // Create a signer recipient to sign the document, identified by name and email
            // We set the clientUserId to enable embedded signing for the recipient
            Signer signer = new Signer();
            signer.setEmail(signerEmail);
            signer.setName(signerName);
            // signer.clientUserId("1000"); # will not receive docuSign email to sign if client user id is present
            signer.recipientId("1");

            SignHere signHere = new SignHere();
            signHere.setAnchorString("/sn1/");
            signHere.setAnchorUnits("pixels");
            signHere.setAnchorYOffset("20");
            signHere.setAnchorXOffset("10");

            Tabs signerTabs = new Tabs();
            signerTabs.setSignHereTabs(Arrays.asList(signHere));
    
            // Add the recipient to the envelope object
            Recipients recipients = new Recipients();
            recipients.setSigners(Arrays.asList(signer));
    
            EnvelopeDefinition envelopeDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition();
            envelopeDefinition.setEmailSubject("Please sign this document");
            envelopeDefinition.setRecipients(recipients);
            
            Path path = Paths.get("./path/to/my/code-examples-java/src/main/resources/World_Wide_Corp_lorem.pdf");
            
            byte[] data = null;
            try {
                data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            Document document = new Document();
            document.setDocumentBase64(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(data));
            document.setName("Hello Doc");
            document.setFileExtension("pdf");
            document.setDocumentId("3");

            envelopeDefinition.setDocuments(Arrays.asList(document));
            // Request that the envelope be sent by setting |status| to "sent".
            // To request that the envelope be created as a draft, set to "created"
            envelopeDefinition.setStatus("sent");
    
            return envelopeDefinition;
        }
    }
```

This code above comes from the Code example launcher [here](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/docusign/controller/eSignature/examples/EG002ControllerSigningViaEmail.java). A pre-packaged version that has all of your configuration details filled in [here](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/) on the Quickstart page is also provided.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I made the changes and replaced the code I was using with the one you posted. Couple of points :
1. The code i was using was from one of the developer pages :
 https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-in-app-embedded/
2. If I use demo.docusign.net in the API client contstructor I see a page not found error
3. With accound-d.docusign.com I see the same error as the one I posted. We are at our wits end on how to make this inegration work. We are acquiring the license but we need to show a demo before that will come through

Comment: Understood.  That first example is based off of the code shown here: https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/docusign/EG001ControllerEmbeddedSigning.java

Comment: I was able to replicate your issue but got it working by adding in restapi onto the end of the basepath so it should be https://demo.docusign.net/restapi. I've updated my snippet to match what you had

Comment: Ok. Good thanks, appreciate the response. We shall check it and let you know if it worked